# How Do I Bring Up The Same Properties Menu As In This Video?

Tags: properties

I am trying to bring up the same menu that is brought up by F6 in [this video](https://youtu.be/WnPkrxz4AQQ?list=PLFt_AvWsXl0djuNM22htmz3BUtHHtOh7v&t=15m28s). But when I press <kbd>F6</kbd> nothing comes up, what do I do?
My Blender version is 2.77.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `fn` + `F6`? If this doesn't work, what type of computer/operating system are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of the video is adjusting the parameters of a newly added object.

In 3d view, add a new object and press F6. But there is a catch: **if you do anything else other than press F6 after creating it**, you don't get the window.

[image: tutorial example]

Many tutorials I've seen over the years teach you to do this through tool shelf, which isn't visible in that video.

[image: another way]

Answer (score 0):

this is the same menu like appear in left panel on bottom - this menu is changing according last function you use. So as first you must add circle by "Shift + A"

Comment: Why minus? This is true and I can't see what exactly Red Death doing, so my answer is to the point and best how can be with information I have ;-) If someone thing that I'm owner of oracular ball, I have some news for him: No, I don't own one :D

Comment: +1 as I don't see what is wrong here. RedDeath you should give more information if this is not what you want.